# DevExtreme mobile: how to filter a dxList using jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter, devextreme

I'm using Devexpress Devextreme Mobile. How can i add a filter in `dxList` with jQuery?

Comment: I tried it. I guess I writing wrong code. I don't know how can i do this.

            $('#FrmOnaylar_Liste').dxList({
            dataSource: data[0].requestsField,
            pullRefreshEnabled: true,
            filter: ['belgeno','=','TSDF7118']
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the `filter` option of the `dataSource`:

```
var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: [/* your data */],
    filter: [/* your filter */]
});

$("#list").dxList({
    // list options
    dataSource: dataSource
});
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/oeq07saf/), as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I get it now. Thank you very much.